# Kotlin compiler throws exception while analysing my use of List.sumOf

Tags: kotlin

I've recently switched to Kotlin 1.5.0 which deprecated `sumBy`, and in the conversion process I've encountered a strange `Exception while analyzing expression` error from the compiler.

Here's a minimal code that produces the error, which you can run [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS40LjAiLCJjb2RlIjoiZnVuIDxUPiBwZXJjZW50aWZ5KGxpc3Q6IExpc3Q8VD4sIGZuOiAoVCkgLT4gQm9vbGVhbik6IEZsb2F0IHtcbiAgICB2YWwgb2tDb3VudCA9IGxpc3Quc3VtT2YgeyBpZiAoZm4oaXQpKSAxIGVsc2UgMCB9XG4gICAgaWYgKGxpc3QuaXNFbXB0eSgpKSByZXR1cm4gMGYgZWxzZSByZXR1cm4gb2tDb3VudC9saXN0LnNpemVcbn1cblxuZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG5cdHZhbCBsaXN0ID0gbGlzdE9mKDEsIDIsIDMpXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihwZXJjZW50aWZ5KGxpc3QpIHsgaXQgJSAyID09IDF9KVxufSIsInBsYXRmb3JtIjoiamF2YSIsImFyZ3MiOiIifQ==):

```kotlin
fun <T> percentify(list: List<T>, fn: (T) -> Boolean): Float {
    val okCount = list.sumOf { if (fn(it)) 1 else 0 }
    if (list.isEmpty()) return 0f else return okCount/list.size
}

fun main() {
    val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    println(percentify(list) { it % 2 == 1})
}
```

My question is, am I using `sumOf` wrong, or is it an issue with the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definetely a bug of the compiler.

If you expicitly specify type of lambda argument(`val okCount = list.sumOf { it: T -> if (fn(it)) 1 else 0 }`), then it will give you another error (`Overload resolution ambiguity.`; this is a known bug, [KT-46360](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46360))

Funny enough, but it able to overcome "resolution ambiguity" in this case if you extract lambda into separate variable (so, you may use it as a workaround):

```kotlin
val lambda = { it: T -> if (fn(it)) 1 else 0 }
val okCount = list.sumOf(lambda)
```

Or, alternatively, you may explicitly cast result of your lambda expression to `Int`:

```kotlin
val okCount = list.sumOf { (if (fn(it)) 1 else 0).toInt() }
```

Also, you need to manually convert `okCount` to `Float`, because ([intentionally](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43310#focus=Comments-27-4506701.0-0)) there is no `sumOf` overload with `Float` return type:

```
return if (list.isEmpty()) 0f else okCount.toFloat() / list.size
```

Comment: Thank you, I submitted a bug report ([KT-46844](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46844)) mentionning your answer.